# strange behaviour with filter?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to extract MIME-like headers (**starting** with [Cc]ontent- ) from a multiline string:

```
scala> val regex = "[Cc]ontent-".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = [Cc]ontent-

scala> headerAndBody
res2: String =
"Content-Type:application/smil
Content-ID:0.smil
content-transfer-encoding:binary
<smil><head>
"
```

This fails

```
scala> headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher(x).matches).toList
res4: List[String] = List()
```

but the "related" cases work as expected:

```
scala> headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher("Content-").matches).toList
res5: List[String] = List(Content-Type:application/smil, Content-ID:0.smil, content-transfer-encoding:binary, <smil><head>)
```

and:

```
scala> headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => x.startsWith("Content-")).toList
res8: List[String] = List(Content-Type:application/smil, Content-ID:0.smil)
```

what am I doing wrong in

```
x => regex.pattern.matcher(x).matches
```

since it returns an empty List??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp should match all line but not only first sub-string.

`val regex = "[Cc]ontent-.*".r`

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the failure with the first line is that you use the `java.util.regex.Matcher.matches()` method that requires a full string match.

To fix that, use the **`Matcher.find()`** method that **searches for the match anywhere inside the input string** and **use the `"^[Cc]ontent-"` regex** (note that the `^` symbol will force the match to appear at the start of the string).

Note that this line of code does not work as you expect:

```
headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher("Content-").matches).toList
```

You run the regex check against the pattern `Content-`, and it is always true (that is why you get all the lines in the result).

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qZGbSq):

```
val headerAndBody = "Content-Type:application/smil\nContent-ID:0.smil\ncontent-transfer-encoding:binary\n<smil><head>"
val regex = "^[Cc]ontent-".r
val s1 = headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher(x).find()).toList
println(s1)
val s2 = headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher("Content-").matches).toList
print (s2)
```

Results (the first is the fix, and the second shows that your second line of code fails):

```
List(Content-Type:application/smil, Content-ID:0.smil, content-transfer-encoding:binary)
List(Content-Type:application/smil, Content-ID:0.smil, content-transfer-encoding:binary, <smil><head>)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: the part with startsWith did work as expected, it produced a useless result obviously, it was just to rule out any errors in the use of filter()

Comment: Sorry, I meant `headerAndBody.lines.filter(x => regex.pattern.matcher("Content-").matches).toList`. All I wrote about referred to this line, sorry for the copy/paste error. I used the right line of code in the demo though.

Comment: The problem with find() is that it might match stuff in the body as well, for example if body was:  <smil><head>
-foo-content-bar-  or something

Comment: If you need to only match in the beginning of a string, you need to use `"^[Cc]ontent-".r` regex then. The caret will anchor the match to the beginning of the string. I updated the answer according to the latest edit.